# What's wrong with my else if statements in spreadsheets

Tags: function, if-statement, excel-formula, helper

This is what I have tried, I am trying to get it to do two different calculations based on a `yes` or `no` answer.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Yes", B2)), (A3*Rules!N9),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("No", B2)), (A3*Rules!N4/100)),
```

Comment: What's happening? How is that different from what you expect?

Comment: ISNUMBER will always return False for cell B2 if it contains text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you make this so long - this should do the trick, and only one IF() necessary:

```
=IF(B2="yes",A3*Rules!N9,A3*Rules!N4/100)
```

However, you could use :

```
=IF(B2="yes",A3*Rules!N9,IF(B2="no",A3*Rules!N4/100,"check"))
```

Which will flag an issue with the contents of B2...

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you this was perfect, it's been along  time since playing with if statements back in vis basic.